# Combine handle different type of publishers

Tags: swift, networking, combine

I am really new to Combine and I'm stuck with this issue. I have basic registration form, that returns empty response with 200 code if everything is ok and 442 if form has some registration failures.

That's the code that can handle empty response and works fine

```
extension Route where ResultType: EmptyResult {
    func emptyResult() -> AnyPublisher<Void, APIError> {
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: urlRequest)
            .print("EMPTY RESULT")
            .tryMap { data, response in
                guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { throw APIError.nonHttpResponse(description: "Not http resp") }
                let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
                
                guard (200..<300).contains(statusCode) else { throw APIError.nonHttpResponse(description: "bad response")
                }
                    return Void()
            }.mapError { error in
                print("Error \(error)")
                return .network(description: error.localizedDescription)
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

However, how I could return publisher with other type? For example

```
struct CustomError: Decodable {
    let usernameError: String
    let emailError: String
}
```

My network call:

```
    API.registration(name: name, email: email, password: password, schoolID: selectedSchool?.id ?? 0)
        .print("Registration")
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { (completion) in
            switch completion {
            case let .failure(error):
                print("ERROR \(error)")
            case .finished: break
            }
        }, receiveValue: { value in
            print(value)
        })
        .store(in: &disposables)
```

Comment: So does your network request always return a `CustomError` as its response?

Comment: Not always, only if there are form validation issues. If there are no form validation issues, I will get empty response with 200 code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a network request, which in case of a successful request, returns a 200 response and an empty body, while in case of a form error, it returns a specific status code and an error in the response.

I would suggest keeping the `Output` type of your `Publisher` as `Void`, however, in case of a form error, decoding the error and throwing it as part of your `APIError`.

```
struct LoginError: Decodable {
    let usernameError: String
    let emailError: String
}

enum APIError: Error {
    case failureStatus(code: Int)
    case login(LoginError)
    case nonHttpResponse(description: String)
    case network(Error)
}

func emptyResult() -> AnyPublisher<Void, APIError> {
    return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: urlRequest)
        .print("EMPTY RESULT")
        .tryMap { data, response in
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { throw APIError.nonHttpResponse(description: "Not http response") }
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

            guard (200..<300).contains(statusCode) else {
                if statusCode == 442 {
                    let loginError = try JSONDecoder().decode(LoginError.self, from: data)
                    throw APIError.login(loginError)
                } else {
                    throw APIError.failureStatus(code: statusCode)
                }
            }
            return Void()
        }.mapError { error in
            switch error {
            case let apiError as APIError:
                return apiError
            default:
                return .network(error)
        }
    }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Then you can handle the specific error by `switch`ing over the `error` in `sink`:

```
API.registration(name: name, email: email, password: password, schoolID: selectedSchool?.id ?? 0)
    .print("Registration")
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { (completion) in
        switch completion {
        case let .failure(error):
            switch error {
            case .login(let loginError):
                print("Login failed, \(loginError.emailError), \(loginError.usernameError)")
            default:
                print(error)
            }
        case .finished: break
        }
    }, receiveValue: { value in
        print(value)
    })
    .store(in: &disposables)
```

Comment: Amazing! However, there is one more question then. In my ViewModel I see, that only network error is thrown, and not the one, we parsed, when status code was 442. Maybe .mapError is overriding thrown error before?

Comment: @AsMartynas well, if your actual network request fails, then yes, `dataTaskPublisher` will fail with error and hence `mapError` will be called, not `tryMap`. However, `dataTaskPublisher` failing with an error means there was no response from the request, since the request itself failed. You need to investigate why is your request failing.

Comment: It's weird because I can print data in status code if statement and AuthError is successfully decoded, so it seems that mapError is called anyway. From logs I see EMPTY RESULT: receive cancel, maybe there is the case?

Comment: @AsMartynas actually my bad, if you throw an error in `tryMap`, that error will be propagated to `mapError` and it won't fail the publisher straight away. Check my updated answer, now `mapError` should handle errors thrown from inside `tryMap` correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If you don't mind, there is one more question. In my ViewModel I call my network request and with .sink(receiveOnCompletion, receiveValue), I try to handle the errors. How could I cast it to my login error? I updated my code above

Comment: @AsMartynas you simply need to `switch` over `error` in the `sink`. Check my updated answer.